# Check: For each of the following permutations $\rho$ in $S(6)$ write $\rho$ as the product of transpositions

Tags: group-theory

For each of the following permutations $\rho$ in $S(6)$ write $\rho$ as the product of transpositions:

1. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$
2. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 &
       3 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2
       \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 &
       4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5
       & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
       6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

Are these correct?

Comment: What's your convention…? I think the second one is wrong.

Comment: You can simplify the second a little by computing the composition first: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 &
    3 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&6&5\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the right-sided convention, in which case they are right.

Comment: So they donot need to be disjoint to do the transpositions? Note I am using the right to left convention

Comment: It is not possible in general to factor as disjoint transpositions, @UsernameUnknown But you can do the second on in far fewer transpositions.

Comment: So Thomas is my answers above correct

Comment: @UsernameUnknown, It is correct. But, you could simplify it down to $(53)(36)(14)$ using Thomas's simplification